# Selecting initial conditions from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, conditional

Let's define a couple of equations:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
d1 = Sqrt[(x - x1)^2 + y^2];
d2 = Sqrt[(x - x2)^2 + y^2];
R = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; U = Sqrt[xp^2 + yp^2]; A = -xp y + x yp;
m1 = 1 - μ;
m2 = μ;
x1 = -μ;
x2 = 1 - μ;
G = 1;
c = 10^4;
μ = 1/2;
ϵ = 1;
ω1 = μ/2 ((1 - μ) - 3);

JC = m1/d1 + m2/d2 + 1/2 (R^2 - U^2) + ϵ/
 c^2 (-(A^2/2) - m1^2/(2 d1^2) - (1/d1 + 1/d2) m1 m2 - (m1 m2)/(
 d1 d2) - m2^2/(2 d2^2) + R^4/8 - A U^2 - (R^2 U^2)/4 - (3 U^4)/
 8 - 3/2 (m1/d1 + m2/d2) (-R^2 + U^2) - 
 7/2 x ((m1 x1)/d1 + (m2 x2)/d2) + 
 3/2 ((m1 x1^2)/d1 + (m2 x2^2)/d2) - 
 1/2 ((m1 x1^2)/d1^3 + (m2 x2^2)/d2^3) y^2 + R^2 ω1);
```

Then we create a two-dimensional grid of initial conditions as follows

```
ICs = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -6, 6, 0.2}, {j, -6, 6, 0.2}], 1];
Ntot = Length[ICs]
```

and then we use a loop procedure in order to obtain some additional information:

```
data = (x0 = #[[1]];
 y0 = 0;
 xp0 = 0;
 C0 = #[[2]];
 JC0 = JC /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, xp -> xp0};
 sol = Solve[JC0 == C0, yp, Reals];
 yp0 = Abs[yp /. sol[[1]]];
 {x0, yp0, C0}) & /@ ICs;
```

As we can see our aim is to determine the value of `yp0`. However for some values of the energy `C0` there is no real solution of `yp0` (energetically forbidden initial conditions). So I want the following: whenever there is no real solution of `yp0` the code should jump this energy level, do not print anything in the `data` list and proceed to the next energetically allowed set of initial conditions.

Comment: Use [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html); something like `yp0 = If[Length@sol > 0, Abs[yp /. sol[[1]]], Nothing]` (not tested).

Comment: @Unfortunately `Nothing` is not recognized in v9.0 which I use.

Comment: `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` should work like `Nothing`.

Comment: @corey979 Indeed it works! However when there is no real solution the code prints in the `data` list only two elements `x0` and `C0`, instead of three. But I want nothing to be printed in this case. So the IF should be somehow expanded also in the printing format.

Comment: It won't be costly to just do `Select[data, Length@# == 3 &]` after `data` is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the `Solve` determines what should be done:

```
yp0 = If[Length@sol > 0, Abs[yp /. sol[[1]]], Nothing]
```

In case of pre-`Nothing` versions of *Mathematica*, `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` works like `Nothing`:

```
yp0 = If[Length@sol > 0, Abs[yp /. sol[[1]]], Unevaluated@Sequence[]]
```

This produces elements of `data` that can contain three (incuding `yp0`) and two (only `x0` and `C0`) elements. I guess some kind of `If` procedure might be constructed to keep only the three-element parts, but it won't be costly in any manner to filter out the unwanted two-element results after the whole `data` is produced:

```
data = Select[data, Length@# == 3 &]
```